# Call Vue method on button click

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am new to Vue and I've been toying around with a basic component and trying to get some interactivity to work. However, when attempting to implement some methods, I find that nothing actually happens. My code looks like this:

```
var testComponent = Vue.component('testComponent', {
    data: function () {},
    props: [ 'maps' ],
    methods: {
        filt: function() {
            alert("Useful alert");
        }
    },
    template: "<div><button class='btn-primary' @click='filt'>Filter</button></div>"
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {},
    methods: {},
    computed: {},
    components: {
        TestComponent: testComponent
    },
    ready: function () {}
});
```

And my HTML essentially contains only this:

```
<test-component></test-component>
```

I would like to call the testComponent's filt method (which will later hopefully become a working filter method for the maps prop), but the button gives no alert on pressing it.

I've tried a few variations like `v-on:click`, but to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Vue will generate the HTML files itself, so you cannot dynamically add HTML which includes Vue methods such as v-on, etc.

Comment: Your code works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/yhutmcx9/1/

Comment: Indeed the fiddle works, so I figured the problem must lie somewhere in my simplification when creating this post.
I had my Vue script in the footer of my page to prevent `element #app not found`-style errors. However, if I put it in the head of the HTML but wrapping it in a `window.onload = function { ...` solved it for me. Are there any obvious drawbacks to this solution?